# How to change the value in the database, after the expiration of time?

Tags: node.js, express

How to change the value in the database, after the expiration of time?

I do a half ban, set the ban time and set banned to true
When ban_expiry becomes no more than the current time, you need to change is_banned true to false.
How to do it?

```
exports.banUnbanUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId } = req.query;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    if (user.banned.status) {
      user.is_banned = false;
      user.ban_expiry = null;
    } else {
      user.is_banned = true;
      user.ban_expiry = new Date() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    }

    await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

```
import { Column, Entity } from "typeorm";
import { Template } from "./Template";

@Entity()
export class User extends Template {
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  full_name!: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  password!: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email!: string;

  @Column({ default: false, nullable: true })
  is_banned: boolean;

  @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
  reason: string;

  @Column({ default: null, nullable: true })
  ban_expiry: Date;
}
```

Comment: can you update the question with the user model? it will help to answer.

Comment: @sumanth Made an update

Comment: What's that "ban_expiry becomes no more" you have mentioned in the question?

Comment: @sumanth ban_expiry is the time for which the user is blocked

Answer (score -1):

To change the `is_banned` true to false when the ban time becomes no more you can use the `cron` library from npm, it allows something on the schedule.

Eg:

run the command in you project directory

```
npm i cron
```

```
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;

const job = new CronJob("* * * * * *", async () => { 
try {
   // your condition here
} catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }

});
job.start();
```

`* * * * * *` - runs every second, you can change the asterisks based on your requirement. see the [docs here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)